# Hover color for custom Button with Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have this custom button and want to apply the background color for the button based on binding. As for the purpose of the button, basically this is a button for a pagination. When the page is unselected, the background is light-gray, and the bg changes to a darker color. But I want the hover effect to be the same. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<Style x:Key="PaginationButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource highlight-gray}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="4">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="content"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource dark-highlight-gray}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
 <Button
     Background="{Binding OutstandingAR_Pagination.Page, Converter={StaticResource PageToBgColorConverter}, ConverterParameter='2'}"
     Style="{StaticResource PaginationButtonStyle}">
     <TextBlock Text="2" />
 </Button>
```

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Dental_Practice_Monitor.Utilities
{
    public class PageToBgColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is int currentPage && parameter != null)
            {
                string param = parameter.ToString();
                int buttonNumber = Helpers.ConvertStringToInteger(param);
                if (currentPage == buttonNumber) 
                {
                    return "#ECECEC";
                }
            }
            return "#FAFAFA";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "#FAFAFA";
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, the background is successfully changing dynamically based on the converter and its parameter but the hover effect is not applied. What did I do wrong or I have to use Binding for the trigger as well?

Comment: It is because the local value including that set by binding has higher precedence than Style setter value. See [Dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence). This is a typicall pitfall when you want to keep hover effect while adding other visual effects.

Comment: Said that, what your conveter actually does?

Comment: @emoacht I just edited the post with the converter class. I looked at the document you provided. So it seems there is no way around this?

Comment: You need to change the way to change Background. So you want to change when the Page value matches Button's TextBox?

Comment: That is correct @emoacht. I changed my strategy to adding borderBrush & borderThickness when hovering but this is the last option I would want to do because if I can't find a solution for this, I will have to keep using borderBrush and borderThickness forever

Comment: @emoacht is right, for this you would typically define an inline Button.Style (BasedOn your custom button style), use a setter that sets the color (instead of setting it locally) and use a Style.Trigger for the IsMouseOver case.